# Reusable HorizontalItemList component in React and Typescript

Tags: react.js, typescript

I'm new to React and need to display a horizontal list of items at several places in my app in differing sizes and styles.

This is a utility component I came up with:

```
function HorizontalItemList<T>({
  items,
  itemToTile,
  style = defaultStyle,
}: HorizontalItemListProps<T>) {
  return (
    <Box
      display={'flex'}
      width={style.width ?? defaultStyle.width}
      height={style.height ?? defaultStyle.height}
      sx={{
        gap: style.gap ?? defaultStyle.gap,
      }}
    >
      {items.map((item, idx) => itemToTile(item, idx))}
    </Box>
  );
}

const defaultStyle: HorizontalItemListStyleProps = {
  gap: 0,
};

export interface HorizontalItemLists<T> {
  items: T[];
  itemToTile: (item: T, idx: number) => ReactNode;

  style?: HorizontalItemListStyleProps;
}

export interface HorizontalItemListStyleProps {
  height?: Property.Height;
  width?: Property.Width;
  gap?: Property.Gap;
}
```

I'm particularly concerned about the way I'm passing the `style` prop. Is there a better way to do this, or is this fine? Any other improvements?

One more query: Should it be HorizontalItemList's responsibility to supply a key prop to each item via something like `cloneElement(item, {{ key: idx }})` (makes HorizontalItemList harder to use incorrectly), or should it be the client code's responsibility (they know better what key to use)?